# $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ be defined by the equation $f(x,y)=(e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ be defined by the equation

$f(x,y)=(e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y)$

> Show that $f$ is one to one on the set $A$ consisting of all $(x,y)$ with $x>0$.

> What is the set $f(A)?$

> If $g$ is inverse function find $Dg(0,1)$

How to solve the last part? I have calculated the jacobian matrix and it comes out $e^{2x}$ so By inverse mapping theorem it is locally invertible. But how can I calculate $f(A)$ and also $Dg(0,1)?$

All are same and $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ then $f(A)=\{(\cos 2t,\sin 2t): \cos t>0\}~?$ In this case the image set is left quadrant?

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: $f(x,y)=f(x,y+2k \pi)$ for every $(x,y)\in A$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ by periodicity of the trigonometric functions (note that $(x,y+2k \pi)\in A$). It follows that $f$ can't be one to one on $A$...

Comment: Can someone verify the added last part. AS I want to clarify my thinking....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For computing $f(A)$, think at the [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and note that 
$$f(A)=f(\{(x,y):x>0\})=\{(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)): r >1, \theta \in [0,2\pi]\}.$$
This is the euclidian plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ where you cut the closed unit ball.
Now for the computation of $Dg(0,1)$, as you mentioned, using the [inverse function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) you can write $$Dg(0,1)= Dg(f(0,\pi/2))= Df(0,\pi/2)^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$